# Cannot install Boost library in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to install Boost library in my ubuntu 12.04 and always getting the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libboost-all-dev : Depends: libboost-iostreams-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-regex-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

I have search for a solution to the `unmet dependencies` issue but nothing seems to work. Can some one help with this ?

I'm getting the above error when running **`sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev`** command on my terminal.

Comment: Does running `sudo apt-get update` change the output of `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev`?

Comment: Also, after running `sudo apt-get update`, what is the output of `sudo aptitude install libboost-all-dev`?

Comment: @BillLynch run **aptitude install** did offer me a way to solve the problem. Thanks, it suggested me to downgrade one package and after do that, the installation of libboost-all-dev ran well. Thanks.